# How can I extract tag names from XML

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to extract the month in here, such that the characters after d: So I can get BC_1MONTH.

`<d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.11</d:BC_1MONTH>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the XML is loaded as a string, you can use regular expressions to match the value between `d:` and `m:`.

```
var str = xml;
var matches = xml.match(/d:(.*)\sm:/);

// get the first match group
console.log(matches[1]); // BC_1MONTH
```

Comment: I thought using regular expressions to parse xml was bad

Comment: @2426021684: it depends on the XML. RSS is ok, but others flavors are a no-go. it comes down to repetitive nested tag names, which RX doesn't like. if a tag never nests inside a tag with it's own name, then RegExp can make short work of reliably parsing out data from XML input. if the XML has validity issues, then RegExp can possible fail or silently mess-up, which a true doc parser would not.

Comment: also note that he's not actually parsing the XML here at all, the structure is not determined, only pattern matches, so the code is fine given valid XML. it could be a lot more precise though. i like `/<d:\w+/g`; short and sweet

Answer (score 0):

Try JS .split metchod:

```
var str='<d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.11</d:BC_1MONTH>';
str= str.split(" "); 
str= str[0].split(":");
console.log(str[1]);
```